# How can I detect global/local view via python?

Tags: python, 3d-view

is there a way to detect what view global or local is active via python?

Can I set them directly somehow or at least always come back to global one?
In a way where if script is executed view is moved to global no matter what view user is in.

Comment: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=local#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.local_view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick:

```
import bpy
is_local_view = sum(bpy.context.space_data.layers[:]) == 0
```

In "local_view" mode all layers disabled, while in "regular" mode one of them always enabled.

Answer (score 5):

This check is using the context, assuming you are in the 3D view already, you can then exit with localview op;

```
if context.space_data.local_view:
    bpy.ops.view3d.localview()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'SpaceConsole' object has no attribute 'local_view' in 2.79

Answer (score 4):

It can be done this way:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        space = area.spaces[0]
        if space.local_view: #check if using local view
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = {'area': area, 'region': region} #override context
                    bpy.ops.view3d.localview(override) #switch to global view
```

Comment: Yes. It works. When I use `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True, use_viewport=True)`, I still got images containing all objects.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Юрий Сивальнев, I searched the API a little more. The Object type has a property `layers_local_view`.  It is an eight member list, all false if the object is not in local view. If you know a particular object you would like to check in the local view space, then you can use this property.

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=local_view#bpy.types.Object.layers_local_view

```
def is_local(ob):
    if ob.layers_local_view[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```