# Checking for object being in local view

Tags: python

a Blender python beginner here. I'm sorry if this is a trivial question but I couldn't find an answer for this anywhere.

I am making a script that checks if selected object is in local view and if it is, it will toggle it back to global view. Something like this:

```
if bpy.context.active_object.local_view_get() == True:
            bpy.ops.view3d.localview
```

However I don't really understand what the viewport parameter should be, I tried to find answer but I guess my understanding of Blender classes is still very poor.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51854/how-can-i-detect-global-local-view-via-python You probably didn't try very hard. Took me 5 seconds on google

Comment: Not really duplicated of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51854/how-can-i-detect-global-local-view-via-python since that question is pre Blender 2.8. Since 2.8 Blender went through major change in its scripts. Many of the solutions from that question no longer work under newer Blender.

Comment: Fair enough, you are right. I am writting an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether certain viewport is in local_view by accessing its local_view property which returns either true/false. First you need to specify the viewport:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
       view_3d = area.spaces.active
```

Then you can access its local_view property:

```
if view_3d.local_view:
   print("Local view active")
else:
   print("Local view not active")
```

Like this it's gonna return the state whenever you run the script. To do this automaticaly whenever the viewport changes you're gonna have to create a custom handler

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work!

Comment: to elaborate your question, To check what objects are visible you would loop through all objects in the scene and do: obj.local_view_get(view3d.local_view) for each. That is according to the docs. Unfortunatelly there seems to be a bug and it always returns False no matter what. My workaround would be to select all objects in the local view which will give you the list you want.